# A java program to prompt the user to guess a number chosen by the computer at random

Tags: java, loops

I am a beginner in Java and I was trying to make this program to choose a random number between 1 and 1000 and prompt the user to guess that number but the program doesn't seem to work and I don't know what's wrong with it.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeBookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        guess();
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 1000.");
        num = input.nextInt();

        if (num >= 1 && num <= 1000)
        {
            while (checkNumber(num) != true)
            {
                System.out.println("Guess again");
                num = input.nextInt();
                checkNumber(num);
            }

            System.out.println("Congratulations. You " +
                            "guessed the number!");
        }
    }

    public static int guess() {
        return ( (int) (1 + Math.random()*1000) );
    }

    public static boolean checkNumber(int a){
      int ans = guess();
      if (a < ans)
      {
          System.out.println("low");
          return false;
      }
      else if (a > ans)
      {
          System.out.println("high");
          return false;
      }
      else
          return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be picking a new random number every time the player guesses. That makes it pretty hard to pin down.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code, sample input and output, and any error messages. Tell us what you expect to happen as well as what's actually happening. This will help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class Guess {
public static void main (String [] args) {
    
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    
    // Generates the Random Number
    int randomNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
    
    System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 1000: ");
    // Get user guess
    int guess = input.nextInt();
    
    while (guess != randomNumber) {
        // Informs the user whether his guess is high or low
        if (guess > randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is high");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your guess is low");
        }
        // Asks the user for another guess
        System.out.print("Make another guess : ");
        guess = input.nextInt();
    }
    
    System.out.println("Congratulations ! You guessed the number");
}
}
```